# automate rman backup when application is down

Tags: shell, plsql

I got a scenario i want to automate rman full backup(hot backup) of database when the application is shutdown on sunday between 1 am and 4 am application admin will shutdown the application what is the best way of approach job needs to run in loop between 1 am - 4 am.

Comment: Try using crontab or timers if you have systemd enabled on your machine

Comment: wirte your script and crontab to execute, just have a try.

Comment: The above comments are definitely a sensible approach, however your question does not appear to be programming-related.  ServerFault is probably a better place to ask system-administration-related questions.

Comment: There is no proper schedule for backup the application might go down at any time.